# How to run Maven for a Java Main Method Call

Tags: java, maven

I am quite new with using maven options - so sorry for an easy question.

I have asked beforehand about how to run java code (call function) and get a clear answer.. but 
it seems something is wrong in this config. Or is it because I am not using a correct parameters for startup?

```
<build>
<plugins>
....
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>java</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
       <mainClass>org.package.Separator.Main</mainClass>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

</plugins>
</build>
```

I am running my POM with  `$:  mvn exec:exec`
And I get such error:

```
One or more required plugin parameters are invalid/missing for 'exec:exec'

[0] Inside the definition for plugin 'exec-maven-plugin' specify the following:

<configuration>
  ...
  <executable>VALUE</executable>
</configuration>

-OR-

on the command line, specify: '-Dexec.executable=VALUE'
```

I have read something about this error and tried originally to move the configuration to executions
secondly - specify classpath but nothing happened((
 My Main function in Separator.java class is like this:

```
static public void main(String[] arg) throws ParserConfigurationException, TransformerException, SAXException, IOException {
  //and here I call for example 
  System.out.println("LOL");
}
```

Some people use: package before goals (for previous versions) but it does not solve my issue.

I have rewrite my POM:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.package.Separator</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

But now Class not found exception at org.package.Separator
I am using mvn package for *compile*

Comment: so you have tried both suggestions printed in the error? Can you show us exactly the command you entered when trying the second `-Dexec.executable=VALUE` option, and what it's errors were?

Comment: I have no idea what I must write as VALUE( I have tried to pass Separator.class but got an error. I have no .jar at this point - this is before project compilation

Comment: You need this code to be available when you run the command. Does the code live in a separate jarfile, or is it part of your project?

if the code that has to run as part of the plugin actually is being built by this maven project then I don't think it'll work. You'll need to build it in a separate pom and depend on it, otherwise I don't think the class file is available.

Comment: I need this code when I am preparing package. I have added <phase>prepare-package</phase> before <goals> and so I could run it with mvn package butnow I am getting class not found exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am running my POM with  $:  mvn exec:exec And I get such error:

Actually you should run

```
$: mvn exec:java
```

See example described on [exec-maven-plugin:java usage](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html).

Finnaly your plugin description should be as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-cli</id>
            <!--<phase>validate</phase>--> <!-- or any other phase you want. -->
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>org.package.Separator</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Note!** This plugin will work only on full name declaration in console or via phase execution:

```
$: mvn org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.2:java
$: mvn integration-test
```

Comment: ok. in such case configure the previous stable version of plugin: 1.2.1. Or run in console: $: mvn clean package org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java -Dexec.mainClass="org.package.Separator.Main"

Comment: do you think the first or the second variant of POM is right for this stable version?

Comment: the first one. the second is completely incorrect and should not work.

Comment: I have changed POM to first variant with only changed version(I have updated plugin also) - and it still shows this error with >VALUE<. But the console variant works - if remove .Main so mainClass="org.package.Separator" so the error is in pom somewhere((

Comment: Now it shows class not found exception : org.package.Separator  perhaps  it is better) anyway

Comment: congratulations! plugin loads test-scope dependencies, not current project itself. if your main class is within current project - plugin would not work.

Comment: I have changed(see question upd) to <phase>prepare-package</phase> but yes the class with main is in project - but could I load it before with mvn package?

Answer (score 1):

First try renaming the classpath of your project `org.package.Separator.Main`

"package" is used in java namespace syntax, so don't use it in your packages classpath.

And maybe you should try adding phase to your goal like this :

```
...
<executions>
    <execution>
       <phase>run</phase>
       <goals>
          <goal>java</goal>
       </goals>
       <configuration>
          <mainClass>org.package.Separator.Main</mainClass>
       </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
...
```

and execute :  `mvn compile run`

Comment: I am trying to use exec plugin - i have no maven compiler plugin

Comment: `exec:java` does not automatically compile your code, you need to do that first.

Comment: Just add maven-compiler-plugin in your pom, and this command will work : `mvn compile run`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. My problem was my code was NOT in src/main/java. your class containing main method must be under src/main/java